# Trace Id not preserved when calling netflix FeignClient

Tags: netflix-feign, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin

I am using spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin and spring-cloud-starter-sleuth as dependency.

When i call a netflix FeignClient call TraceId changes...

```
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.FeignClient;

@FeignClient
public interface TesterClient {
@RequestLine("GET /testCall")
@Headers({"Authorization: Bearer {bearerToken}",
        "Content-Type: application/json"})
ResponseEntity<Test> testMethod(@Param("bearerToken") String bearerToken);
}

@Bean
public TesterClient testerClient() {
    return Feign.builder()
            .decoder(new TestDecoder()).encoder(new TestEncoder())
            .logLevel(Logger.Level.FULL).target(TesterClient.class, 
this.testUrl);
}
```

When i call TesterClient the traceId changes? How could i preserve the same traceId?

Comment: Which version of sleuth are you using?

Comment: <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth</artifactId>
<version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>

Comment: Please try the latest versions available. 2.1.0 is not the latest one

Comment: tried using 2.1.1.RELEASE but still no use.
Whenever a FeignClient is invoked traceId changes..

Comment: Can you file an issue at Github with a sample?